# Heroku deployment failed : FATAL: role "ckinvlxnnpaagi" is not permitted to log in

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, spring-data-jpa

I upload the sample app to heroku and I have created the postgress database and I was able to connect using the heroku client using the same credentials provided by heroku database and when I go my app https://spring-boot-api-crud.herokuapp.com/

> heroku logs --tail --app spring-boot-api-crud

Any idea what is the error about?

```
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404332+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404332+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404332+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404332+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404333+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404333+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404333+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404334+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404334+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404334+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404334+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404335+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404336+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404337+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404341+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404341+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.guides.springboot2.crud.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404341+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404342+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404342+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404342+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404342+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404343+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404343+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404343+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404343+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404531+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.404  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: role "ckinvlxnnpaagi" is not permitted to log in
2021-01-22T01:44:00.407672+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.407  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.412376+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.412  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.461163+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.460  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2021-01-22T01:44:00.461165+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T01:44:00.461166+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465789+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.465 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465790+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465805+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465806+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465806+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465807+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465808+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465808+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465809+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465810+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465810+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465811+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465811+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465812+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465812+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465813+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465814+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465815+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465815+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465816+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.guides.springboot2.crud.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465817+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465817+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465818+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465818+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275-heroku]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465819+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465819+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465820+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465827+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465828+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465828+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465829+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465829+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465829+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465833+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465834+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465834+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465834+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465835+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465835+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465835+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465836+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465836+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465837+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465837+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465837+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465838+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465838+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465839+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 24 common frames omitted
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465839+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465839+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465840+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465840+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465845+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465845+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465845+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465846+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 41 common frames omitted
2021-01-22T01:44:00.465846+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T01:44:00.563064+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T01:44:00.600932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-22T01:44:43.067940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=spring-boot-api-crud.herokuapp.com request_id=8ea3adeb-6c57-4f6d-879c-c00b610de7f7 fwd="75.10.187.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T01:44:43.690399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=spring-boot-api-crud.herokuapp.com request_id=2cd4e5f1-6c5f-4c5f-8589-33ad5bcba06f fwd="75.10.187.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source of your problem is here:

```
2021-01-22T01:44:00.404531+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-22 01:44:00.404  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: role "ckinvlxnnpaagi" is not permitted to log in
```

The role looks like a Heroku database name. Check your database login credentials - URL, username, password.

Good luck.